# Is there a possible lifetime issue with the derived class pointer here?

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism, stdthread

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class IA
{
    public:
        virtual ~IA() = default;
        virtual void foo(void) = 0;
};

class A : public IA
{
    private:
        int x;
    
    public:
        A(int _x) : x(_x) {}
        void foo(void) { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr<IA> ia_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(10);
    auto t1 = std::thread(&A::foo, dynamic_cast<A*>(ia_ptr.get()));
    
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a simplified view of a piece of code that I'm working on.
I need to call the function foo (implementation in the derived class `A::foo`) using a thread.

Since the object of the derived class is only accessible (design constraint) through the `unique_ptr` to the base class, therefore I'm calling the thread object as:

`std::thread t1 = std::thread(&A::foo, dynamic_cast<A*>(ia_ptr.get()));`

My first question here is that since the lifetime of of the object of A is as long as the lifetime of the program (as the unique_ptr in this case is only destroyed when the program exits), is there any lifetime/dangling pointer type risk associated with invoking the thread object in the manner I've shown above?

My second question is that since `foo()` is only implemented in `A::foo`, is there any conceptual difference between `std::thread(&A::foo, dynamic_cast<A*>(ia_ptr.get()));` and `std::thread(&IA::foo, ia_ptr.get());`? The way I see it, in both cases the same implementation of `foo()` is called using the same instance of `A`.

Is this interpretation correct?

Just FYI, the code compiles with both methods.

Comment: FWIW, `auto t1 = std::thread([&](){ ia_ptr->foo(); });` is a lot easier to read and understand.

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated the code with the auto type deduction for the thread object.

Comment: @user3224083 NathanOliver was also referring to the use of a lambda, not just `auto` deduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `A::foo()` should be marked as `override`:

```cpp
class A : public IA
{
    ...
    
    public:
        ...
        void foo(void) override { ... }
};
```

That said, in this situation, making the `std::thread` directly call `A::foo()` using a type-casted `IA*`-to-`A*` pointer would defeat the purpose of using `IA` at all.  You may as well just get rid of `IA` altogether and use `A` by itself:

```cpp
auto a_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(10);
auto t1 = std::thread(&A::foo, a_ptr.get());
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `IA` then you should actually use it.  Make the `std::thread` call `IA::foo()` instead, using the original `IA*` pointer, and let polymorphism dispatch the call to `A::foo()` normally:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<IA> ia_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(10);
auto t1 = std::thread(&IA::foo, ia_ptr.get());
```

Or, even better, don't even have the `std::thread` call either `foo()` directly at all. Use a lambda instead, and let the compiler work out the correct dispatch to call `foo()` for you:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<IA> ia_ptr = std::make_unique<A>(10);
auto t1 = std::thread([&](){ ia_ptr->foo(); });
```

And no, there is no dangling pointer issue here, since as you said, the `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed *after* the thread is done using it.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason behind your recommendation to not call the function using a type-casted pointer? Is it just a good practice thing, or something deeper than that?